# How do loop over the search results for a byte string and offset the resultant pointer (in WinDbg)?

Tags: windbg

I'm attempting to search for an arbitrarily long byte string in WinDbg and print out the address if an integer in the vicinity meets some criteria.

Pseudo-register $t0 contains the starting address I want to search.

Here's something that, based on the [Windows docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/s--search-memory-), maybe could work (though it clearly doesn't).

```
.foreach (place { s -[1] @$t0 L?30000 00 00 00 00  00 20 00 00 }) { .if ( (place +0x8) <= 0x1388) { .printf "0x%x\n", place } }
```

### Search

First, the search command doesn't quite work correctly. I only want the address of the match (not the data).

```
s -[1] @$t0 L?30000 00 00 00 00  00 20 00 00
```

The docs say that the `1` flag will only return the address. When I issue that command, WinDbg replies

> ^ Syntax error in 's -[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/s--search-memory-) @$t0 L?30000 00 00 00 00  00 20 00 00 '

If I leave out the `-1`, it finds two matches.

What am I doing wrong here?

### Condition

I don't think the condition is behaving the way I want. I want to look at the third dword starting at `place`, i.e. place+8, and verify that it's smaller than 5000 (decimal). The .if inside the .foreach isn't printing a meaningful value for place (i.e. the address returned from the search). I think it's dereferencing place first and comparing the value of that integer to 5000. How do I look at the value of, say, `*(int*)(place+8)`?

### Documentation?

The docs are not helping me very much. They only have sparse examples, none of which correspond to what I need.
Is there better documentation somewhere besides MS's Hardware Dev Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start writing JavaScript  for a more legible way of scripting

old way

```
0:000> s -b vect l?0x1000 4d
00007ff7`8aaa0000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
00007ff7`8aaa00d4  4d 90 80 d2 df f9 82 d3-4d 90 80 d2 52 69 63 68  M.......M...Rich
00007ff7`8aaa00dc  4d 90 80 d2 52 69 63 68-4c 90 80 d2 00 00 00 00  M...RichL.......

0:000> s -[1]b vect l?0x1000 4d
0x00007ff7`8aaa0000
0x00007ff7`8aaa00d4
0x00007ff7`8aaa00dc
```

using javascript

```
function search(addr,len)
{
    var index = []
    var mem = host.memory.readMemoryValues(addr,len)
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(mem[i] == 0x4d)
        {
            index.push(addr+i)    
        }
    }
    return index
}
```

executed will return address like which you can manipulate further

```
0:000> dx -r1 @$scriptContents.search(0x00007ff78aaa0000,1000)
@$scriptContents.search(0x00007ff78aaa0000,1000)                 : 140701160046592,140701160046804,140701160046812
    length           : 0x3
    [0x0]            : 0x7ff78aaa0000
    [0x1]            : 0x7ff78aaa00d4
    [0x2]            : 0x7ff78aaa00dc
```

improving the script a little to find something based on first result
we will try to find the **index of Rich string**  that follows the **character 'M'**

modified script

```
function search(addr,len)
{
    var index = []
    var Rich = []
    var result = []
    var mem = host.memory.readMemoryValues(addr,len)
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(mem[i] == 0x4d)
        {
            index.push(addr+i)
            var temp = host.memory.readMemoryValues(addr+i+4,1,4)
            host.diagnostics.debugLog(temp +"\t")
            if(temp == 0x68636952)
            {
                Rich.push(addr+i)
            }
        }
    }
    result.push(index)
    result.push(Rich)
    return result
}
```

result only the third occurance of char "M" is followed by Rich string

```
0:000> dx -r2 @$scriptContents.search(0x00007ff78aaa0000,1000)
3   3548576223  1751345490  @$scriptContents.search(0x00007ff78aaa0000,1000)                 : 140701160046592,140701160046804,140701160046812,140701160046812
    length           : 0x2
    [0x0]            : 140701160046592,140701160046804,140701160046812
        length           : 0x3
        [0x0]            : 0x7ff78aaa0000
        [0x1]            : 0x7ff78aaa00d4
        [0x2]            : 0x7ff78aaa00dc
    [0x1]            : 140701160046812
        length           : 0x1
        [0x0]            : 0x7ff78aaa00dc
0:000> s -b vect l?0x1000 4d
00007ff7`8aaa0000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
00007ff7`8aaa00d4  4d 90 80 d2 df f9 82 d3-4d 90 80 d2 52 69 63 68  M.......M...Rich
00007ff7`8aaa00dc  4d 90 80 d2 52 69 63 68-4c 90 80 d2 00 00 00 00  M...RichL.......
```

`load the extensension jsprovider.dll` **.load jsprovider**
write a script say **foo.js**
load the script   **.scriptload ...\path\foo.js**
execute any functions inside the js you wrote with **dx @$scriptContents.myfunc(myargs)**

see below using cdb just for ease of copy paste windbg works just as is

```
F:\>type mojo.js
function hola_mojo ()
{
        host.diagnostics.debugLog("hola mojo this is javascript \n")
}

F:\>cdb -c ".load jsprovider;.scriptload .\mojo.js;dx @$scriptContents.hola_mojo();q" cdb | f:\usr\bin\grep.exe -A 6 -i reading
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.load jsprovider;.scriptload .\mojo.js;dx @$scriptContents.hola_mojo();q'
JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'F:\mojo.js'
hola mojo this is javascript
@$scriptContents.hola_mojo()
quit:
```

Comment: How do I use JavaScript in windbg?

Comment: load the jsprovider extension write a script load and execute the js function that you wrote  I edited the post to add some details take a look

Comment: Why did I never know this? I never noticed the base WinDbg docs referring to any other command language than the cryptic one that's built in.

Answer (score 1):

If I read this part of the documentation

> `s [-[[Flags]Type]] Range Pattern`

correctly, you cannot leave out `Type` when specifying flags. That's because the flags are inside two square brackets. Otherwise it would have been noted as `s [-[Flags][Type]] Range Pattern`.

Considering this, the example works:

```
0:000> .dvalloc 2000
Allocated 2000 bytes starting at 00ba0000
0:000> eb 00ba0000 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
0:000> eb 00ba1000 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
0:000> s -[1]b 00ba0000 L?2000 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
0x00ba0000
0x00ba1000
```

Also note that you'll have a hidden bug for the use of `place`: it should be `${place}`. By default, that will work with the address (line break for readability on SO):

```
0:000> .foreach (place {s -[1]b 00ba0000 L?2000 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 }) 
       { .if ( (${place} +0x8) < 0xba1000) { .printf "0x%x\n", ${place} } }
0xba0000
```

In order to read a DWord from that address, use the `dwo()` MASM oerator (line break for readability on SO):

```
0:000> .foreach (place {s -[1]b 00ba0000 L?2000 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 }) 
       { .if ( (dwo(${place} +0x8)) < 0xba1000) 
          { .printf "0x%x = 0x%x\n", ${place}, dwo(${place}+8) } }
0xba0000 = 0x9
0xba1000 = 0x9
```